# How can I suppress RemoteCommand option in ssh

Tags: ssh

My company's security requires me to use scp with the -S switch that is then used to login to one system and from it ssh to another. I have openssh 7.9, so when I use that switch, it adds RemoteCommand=none to its options. However, the remote system has an older ssh that doesn't understand this option and fails with an error.

Is there a way to suppress this option ?

Comment: Same boat......